# Is it okay to 'abuse' re-assignment?

Tags: python

Because I don't like using `\` to break long lines (to comply with PEP8), I tend to do something like this:

```
message = "There are {} seconds in {} hours."
message = message.format(nhours*3600, nhours)
print(message)
```

It also makes code cleaner. Is this an okay way of doing things?

Comment: Not really a Code Review, I feel this is more appropriate at [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this is perfectly *on-topic* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more than okay, it is nicely readable, has no problems and involves no abuse whatsoever. I sometimes do the same.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing necessarily wrong with doing that - I use that for situations that the message would be used more than once. However, for one-shot, multiline messages I'd do:

```
message =  "There are %d seconds " % nhours*3600
message += "in %d hours." % nhours
print message
```

Honestly, the only difference is stylistic. I prefer this method because it places the variables directly within the string, which I feel is more readable.

Comment: What does `it places the variables directly within the string` mean?

Comment: Maybe a bad wording there. I mean that since the variable is assigned in the same line as the string, it's a bit clearer what goes where. In fact, I'd prefer `msg = "There are " + nhours*3600 + " seconds in " + nhours + " hours."` but I'm not certain whether you can do that in Python.

Comment: That's a lot uglier I think, but yeah you can do that. You just need to convert your integers to string: `msg = "There are " + str(nhours*3600) + " seconds in " + str(nhours) + " hours."`.

Comment: Like I said, matter of personal style :)

Comment: You do lose reuseability which is important to note (without putting this code in a function). Ofcourse this isn't relevant if you only format once.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: What reusability do you lose?

Comment: @Tshepang: Both of our formats only allow for one use: Yours because the format overwrites the template, and mine because the message is constructed in situ.

Comment: @Michael: I'm referring to the possible reuse if you wouldn't overwrite. :)