# Finding unique/obsolete binary Debian packages

Tags: python, linux

I have a script I use to prune packages that have gone stale from my custom Debian repository (i.e. they no longer exists on any of the official repositories):

```
import apt_pkg
import gzip
import subprocess


CUSTOM_REPO = ("/home/tshepang/.custom_repo/dists/tshepang/main/"
               "binary-amd64/Packages.gz")
TEMPLATE = ("/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_{}_{}_"
            "binary-amd64_Packages")
CODENAMES = 'jessie sid experimental'.split()
ARCHIVE_AREAS = "main contrib non-free".split()


def main():
    custom_repo = apt_pkg.TagFile(gzip.open(CUSTOM_REPO))
    wheezy_packages = list()
    for codename in CODENAMES:
        for archive_area in ARCHIVE_AREAS:
            repo = TEMPLATE.format(codename, archive_area)
            repo = apt_pkg.TagFile(gzip.open(repo, "rb"))
            wheezy_packages.extend([pkg["Package"] for pkg in repo])
    for package in custom_repo:
        package_name = package["Package"]
        if package_name not in wheezy_packages:
            cmd = "apt-cache policy " + package_name
            subprocess.call(cmd.split())
            choice = raw_input("remove from cache [Y/n]? ")
            if not choice or choice.lower().startswith("y"):
                cmd = ("reprepro -vv --basedir /home/tshepang/.custom_repo/ "
                       "remove tshepang " + package_name)
                subprocess.call(cmd.split())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I strongly suspect the code can be better.

As a sidenote, here is sample UI:

> ```
> apache2.2-common:
>       Installed: (none)
>       Candidate: 2.2.22-13
>       Version table:
>          2.2.22-13 0
>             500 file:/home/tshepang/.custom_repo/ tshepang/main amd64 Packages
>     remove from cache [Y/n]? 
>     removing 'apache2.2-common' from 'tshepang|main|amd64'...
>     Exporting indices...
>     Deleting files no longer referenced...
>     deleting and forgetting pool/main/a/apache2/apache2.2-common_2.2.22-13_amd64.deb
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks very good, so I'll just propose some minor (and subjective) improvements:

- Imports: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) has some recommendations about grouping imports that sound pretty reasonable.
- `("s1" "s2")`: I don't know what the orthodoxy says, but I prefer an explicit `+` in between.
- `list()`: Why not `[]`?
- `wheezy_packages.extend([pkg["Package"] for pkg in repo])` -> `wheezy_packages.extend(pkg["Package"] for pkg in repo)`.
- `repo = a`, then `repo = f(repo)`. IMHO this is as common a pattern as is undesirable. Different values *deserve* different variable names (key point of functional programming).
- Function too long: I'd split the code in at least two auxiliary functions, one to get `wheezy_packages` and another to run the commands.

Comment: `list()` was inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745292

Comment: Is the explicit `+` in this case common practice?

Comment: Regarding the different values comment, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1719.

Comment: 1) `list()` A.M. is certainly a reference to follow. 2) `+` I prefer to write it, but not really sure what's better/more idiomatic. 3) I strongly disagree with that answer. In that example I'd use `message_pattern` and `pattern`, as I said in the answer, different values, different names. Do you know some Ruby. Those are my ideas about FP (99% can be applied to Python): http://www.slideshare.net/tokland/functional-programming-with-ruby-9975242

Comment: Am not really familiar with Ruby.